# How to make the link is clickable in textarea in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

- I have a page named Community where user can comment on another post
- I have a problem when user comments the link but it's not displayed true

[When user comments, the link is not displayed true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPdsy.png)

- The function I used to convert the text to link

```
const convertToLink = (text) => {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    var text1 = text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
    var exp2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    return text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a  href="http://$2">$2</a>');
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot render HTML inside of textarea. Use `<p>` instead

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: convertToLink(text) }}></p>
```

Comment: It worked, many thanks to brother !!

Comment: One more note: You should use `sanitize` to format your html code before put it to dangerouslySetInnerHTML for preventing `Exploiting script injection`
https://github.com/zacharystenger/sanitize-html-react